# Error Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, getelementsbytagname

```
$(function() {
    $.get('http://localhost/rand.php', function(data){
        document.getElementsByName('login')[0].value='data';
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

what is the problem in these code. they are giving me error like "background.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined".

Comment: You could try `document.getElementsByTagName('input')...`

Answer (score 3):

Do you have `name=login` element in your `HTML` page, if no then you cannot get the element and its value.

You can have something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="login" value="OK">
```

Then you can get this element by name and then get the value.

Below is what I tried:

```
function onLoad() {
    var value= document.getElementsByName('login')[0].value;
    alert("value="+value); // value=OK
}
```